.NET WinForms: How to get kind of a screenshot from what's "behind" a form?
Let rect be the left, top, width, height of a form that is being displayed at the current screen. Now, I want to take a "screenshot" of what's displayed "behind" on the desktop.
Motivation: I'm sure all of you know a TV station that displays a clock in some corner of the screen. Most of these clocks do have a fail: They don't adapt to the background, like the clock is being displayed at the top-right corner, and the font color has been set to pure white. Assume the weather forecast, displaying Bob Ross' fluffy little white clouds. What time is it? Ermh...
What I want to do is to take a screenshot of the very same area my clock will be shown at, and calculate a more-or-less contrasting color from that area (rect).
Any hints? Just on how to get the Background rectangle! Thanks!
